# Optimizing loop for by using vectors python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I created following code:

```
M=20000
sample_all = np.load('sample.npy')  
sd = np.zeros(M)
chi_arr = np.zeros((M,4))
sigma_e = np.zeros((M,41632))
mean_sigma = np.zeros(M)
max_sigma = np.zeros(M)
min_sigma = np.zeros(M)
z = np.load('z_array.npy')
prof = np.load('profile_at_sources.npy')
L = np.load('luminosities.npy')

for k in range(M):
    sd[k]=np.array(sp.std(sample_all[k,:]))
    arr = np.genfromtxt('samples_fin1.txt').T[2:6]
    arr_T = arr.T
    chi_arr[k,:] = arr_T[k,:]               
    sigma_e[k,:]=np.sqrt(calc(z,prof,chi_arr[k,:], L))
    mean_sigma[k] = np.array(sp.mean(sigma_e[k,:]))
    max_sigma[k] = np.array(sigma_e[k,:].max())
    min_sigma[k] = np.array(sigma_e[k,:].min())
```

where calc(...) is a function that calculates some stuff (is not important for my question)

This loop takes, for M=20000, about 27 hours on my machine. It's enough... There's a way to optimize it, maybe with vectors instead of loop for?

For me it's really simple create loop, my head thinks with loops for this kind of code... It's my limitation... Could you help me? thanks

Comment: Could you move ```arr = np.genfromtxt('samples_fin1.txt').T[2:6]``` and ```arr_T = arr.T``` outside the loop? Looks like a timekiller to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like each of the k-th rows that are created in your various arrays are independent of each k-th iteration of your for loop and only dependent on rows of sigma_e... so you could parallelize it over many workers. Not sure if the code is 100% kosher but you didn't provide a working example.
Note this only works if each k-th iteration is COMPLETELY independent of each k-1th iteration.

```
M=20000
sample_all = np.load('sample.npy')  
sd = np.zeros(M)
chi_arr = np.zeros((M,4))
sigma_e = np.zeros((M,41632))
mean_sigma = np.zeros(M)
max_sigma = np.zeros(M)
min_sigma = np.zeros(M)
z = np.load('z_array.npy')
prof = np.load('profile_at_sources.npy')
L = np.load('luminosities.npy')
workers = 100
arr = np.genfromtxt('samples_fin1.txt').T[2:6] # only works if this is really what you're doing to set arr.

def worker(k_start, k_end):
    for k in range(k_start, k_end + 1):
        sd[k]=np.array(sp.std(sample_all[k,:]))
        arr_T = arr.T
        chi_arr[k,:] = arr_T[k,:]        


    sigma_e[k,:]=np.sqrt(calc(z,prof,chi_arr[k,:], L))
    mean_sigma[k] = np.array(sp.mean(sigma_e[k,:]))
    max_sigma[k] = np.array(sigma_e[k,:].max())
    min_sigma[k] = np.array(sigma_e[k,:].min())

threads = []
kstart = 0
for k in range(0, workers):
    T = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[0 + k * M / workers, (1+ k) * M / workers - 1 ])
    threads.append(T)
    T.start()

for t in threads:
  t.join()
```

Edited following comments:
Seems like [there's a mutex that CPython places on all objects](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) that prevents parallel access. Use IronPython or Jython to step around this. Also, you can move the file read outside if you're really just deserializing the same array from samples_fin1.txt.

Comment: "so you could parallelize it over many workers." using threads will not provide any speed up and could end up actually slowing the whole thing down.

Comment: See about the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). You could potentially speed things up by chunking the work in _multiprocessing_ but a definite easy win is getting `arr = np.genfromtxt('samples_fin1.txt').T[2:6]` out of a loop to stop 20000 I/O operations

Comment: @roganjosh I didn't know about that. Good point, but it seems like Jython or Ironpython can be used to avoid a mutex on sigma_e. I'll edit to note the IO optimization.

Comment: I think switching to IronPython or Jython might be a bit of an extreme move. Numpy vectorized calculations can step around the GIL with no issues (though by using threads I think you disrupt this). The OP has hand-waved `calc()` but I suspect that it's important to actually answering this.

Comment: @roganjosh the code OP provided seems to only be slicing sigma_e and building a ~80000000 element matrix, seems to be fair to reason there shouldn't be much reason it's taking 27 hours to execute. I also think calc() could be the culprit but this is the quick and dirty solution. The loop is performing something like 4 * m * 40000 assignments, should be on the order of minutes to execute, not days. Plus side of threading it and using a different interpreter is the optimization also reaches calc() without knowing what operations its performing.

Comment: That's a fair point. If you wanted to continue with your suggested approach in CPython then you could switch to the multiprocessing module. Chunk the inputs to be calculated and pass each chunk to a different process. Then recombine the results at the end. Each process is bound by the GIL but each process has its own

Comment: Thanks to all! calc(...) is a function that calculates the Hubble parameter (so a square-root of a quantity)...   Now I try to understand your code